# rails show each category content

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is how my CategoriesController looks like:

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController

  def index     
    @categories = Category.all
  end

  def show
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])          
  end   

end
```

inside my show.html.erb I wrote this to display the category name:

```
<h2><%= @category.name %></h2>
```

I also have a PagesController which I made relations with the Category 
I have few Pages assigned to Category (for example category_id: 1)
When I click on the category link from my homepage:

```
<%= link_to "category", category_path(cat) %>
```

It goes to the show page which is great
**How can I display** on the show.html.erb **all the Pages that belongs to this category** that I've clicked on?

Comment: Have you sent associations between `category` and `page`. If yes, what are those?

Comment: on my category model: has_many :pages, on my page model: belongs_to :category, and this is what I have on my schema: add_index "pages", ["category_id"], name: "index_pages_on_category_id"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call the pages assosication with the category model as,

```html
<%= @category.name %>
<h1> PAGES </h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <% @category.pages.each do |page| %>
      <td> <%= page.title %> </td>
      <td> <%= page.content %> </td>
   <% end %>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This will do for you.

Comment: Okay, Please accept my answer if you are interested. :-) happy coding in ruby.

Comment: OK, you just forgot to close the tags after the |page| and add it before the end %>

Comment: some times, if you have 4 to 5 lines of ruby code such as a do block without any html, you can even open <% at the first lien and close at last %>   `<% @caregory.page.each do |page| \n
 title = page.title \n
 content =  page.content \n
        end %>`

Comment: take \n as next line. Written this so that It may help you any where.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`includes`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) for enhanced performance of your application. It will return all expected records from `pages` also and that's without firing database query again. `@category.pages` in ERB will not make database query. Hence, you will have efficient code.

In your show action:

```
def show
  @category = Category.find(params[:id]).includes(:pages)
end
```

In `show.html.erb`:

```
<%= "Category: #{@category.name}" %>
<h1> POSTS </h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <% @category.pages.each do |page| %>
      <td> <%= page.field1 %> </td>
      <td> <%= page.field2 %> </td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

*Rich Peck edit*

Normally, `ActiveRecord` does something called [`lazy loading`](http://www.spritle.com/blogs/2011/03/17/eager-loading-and-lazy-loading-in-rails-activerecord/), which means that it will only execute a DB query when it needs to. This is normally highly efficient; unfortunately causes a problem when you call associative data.

When calling `@category.pages`, you get the [`n+1` issue](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations), which means that each time you call the `Category.find` query, an *extra* query will be used to load the `pages`:

> The above code will execute just 2 queries, as opposed to 11 queries in the previous case:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM clients LIMIT 10
> SELECT addresses.* FROM addresses
>   WHERE (addresses.client_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
> ```

So using `.includes` essentially appends all the `pages` to your `@category`, making it much more efficient than letting it load lazily.

Comment: This is known as `eager loading` if you wanted to look it up

Comment: Thanks @RichardPeck for adding more info.

Answer (score 0):

Well mostly it depends on how you made your relationships between `category` and `page`. With what i can see from your code, you can do something like this.

```
@pages = Page.where(:category_id => 1)
```

**Update**

As per to your relationships

```
@pages = @category.pages
```